# Decode AES encryption in web application in IBM Liberty server

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

Placed the AES encryption password in liberty server jvm.options file as below
-DencKey={aes}{aes}ANRib/ITz7RTc2YB+VXWZqINrjZ15vSBeg== ........

while retrieving in java application by using System.getProperty("encKey").

getting the exact value not the decrypted one.

Should we do  decrypt manually or through configurations we can achieve the decrypted value ?

Comment: I looked at the Knowledge Center for Liberty and searched for the AES topics and found this one https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwlp_pwd_encrypt.html and from reading that it looks like the only file that can have the encryption in it is the server.xml. But I have not tried what you are doing, so I can not say for sure.  I think you already understand the steps in this video I made: https://youtu.be/pJ2GVR-I6dg

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to enable the [passwordUtilities-1.0 feature](https://openliberty.io/docs/20.0.0.8/reference/feature/passwordUtilities-1.0.html):

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>passwordUtilities-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

Then, you can use the [com.ibm.websphere.crypto.PasswordUtil API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.liberty.doc/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.passwordUtil_1.0-javadoc/com/ibm/websphere/crypto/PasswordUtil.html) to decode the password:

```
String encodedPassword = System.getProperty("encKey");
String decodedPassword = PasswordUtil.decode(encodedPassword);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your encoded string is malformed

`-DencKey={aes}{aes}ANRib/ITz7RTc2YB+VXWZqINrjZ15vSBeg==...`

it should only have a single encryption preamble like

`-DencKey={aes}ANRib/ITz7RTc2YB+VXWZqINrjZ15vSBeg==...`

Answer (score 0):

for ppl who find this on their search to decode the PW:
here an example to decode with passwordUtilities feature

https://github.com/TiloGit/liberty-pw-util/tree/master/dyn-pw

https://gitlab.com/pppoudel/public_shared/-/tree/master/WLibertyPwdUtil

blog post of it:
https://purnapoudel.blogspot.com/2017/10/how-to-use-wlp-passwordutilities.html

important to have the enc key set.

```xml
  <variable name="wlp.password.encryption.key" value="myEncKey123">
```

code example:

```jsp
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<%@page language="java"
    contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>index</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
     <%! String password="t3mp_pwD"; %>
     <h2> This page shows how to use com.ibm.websphere.crypto.PasswordUtil to encrypt/decrypt password using xor or aes.</h2>
     <hr/>
     <h3> Provided plain text password is:<%= password %></h3>
     Note: encryption key "replaceM3" is being used for "aes" encryption/decryption. <br/>
     <br/>
     <%! String xorEncodedVal=com.ibm.websphere.crypto.PasswordUtil.passwordEncode(password, "xor");
         String aesEncodedVal=com.ibm.websphere.crypto.PasswordUtil.passwordEncode(password, "aes"); %>
     <h3> xor encoded value is: <%= xorEncodedVal %> </h3>
     <h3> aes encrypted value is: <%= aesEncodedVal %> </h3>
     <h3> xor decoded value is: <% out.println(com.ibm.websphere.crypto.PasswordUtil.passwordDecode(xorEncodedVal)); %> </h3>
     <h3> aes decrypted value is: <% out.println(com.ibm.websphere.crypto.PasswordUtil.passwordDecode(aesEncodedVal)); %> </h3> 
     
</body>
</html>
```