# Can you encrypt regular variables in IBM/Open Liberty using securityUtility?

Tags: encryption, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

Liberty allows us to encode/encrypt password data. However, is this only for designated Liberty password fields? Or would Liberty automatically decrypt my custom variable if the value was an encrypted `{aes}` value generated by securityUtility?

Example:

```
<variable name="my.sensitive.var" value="{aes}blAhBlahAblah" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode/encrypt variable values and substitute them for password fields in the config or use them in your application, where you'll need to decrypt them using the [Password Utilities](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/feature/passwordUtilities-1.1.html) feature's [APIs](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/javadoc/api/passwordUtilities-1.1.com.ibm.websphere.crypto.html?path=23.0.0.8/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.authData_1.0-javadoc/com/ibm/websphere/crypto/PasswordUtil.html).

However, you can't use the encoded/encrypted values for other things in the config that are not marked as `ibm:type="password"` in the metadata.
For example:

```
   <variable name="thisWillWork" value="{aes}APaWnx/wThHwqThFdjUparDSMKJZV9KnPY5OPfSE5y0F" />
   <variable name="thisWillNotWork" value="{aes}APaWnx/wThHwqThFdjUparDSMKJZV9KnPY5OPfSE5y0F" />
   <basicRegistry id="basic">
      <user name="${thisWillNotWork}" password="${thisWillWork}" />
   </basicRegistry>
```

For more information regarding using encrypted/encoded values in your app, take a look at this stackoverflow question: [Decode AES encryption in web application in IBM Liberty server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64888285/decode-aes-encryption-in-web-application-in-ibm-liberty-server)

Answer (score 1):

Only for data tagged as sensitive using ibm:type="password" in metatype - an example [here](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/97c0f7a50b8514b6ecf8d946331ff5938577251c/dev/com.ibm.ws.security.auth.data.common/resources/OSGI-INF/metatype/metatype.xml#L21)

More info that might help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64888285/decode-aes-encryption-in-web-application-in-ibm-liberty-server)